# Issue starting mongodb enterprise version 4.2

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run the server of mongodb using the enterprise version. I already had the previous version of mongodb (3.4 standalone) installed in my system (not sure if this can be related).

```
2020-03-19T13:18:12.169-0700 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.180-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=90709 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Maias-MacBook-Pro.local    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.180-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.180-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.180-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: enterprise     
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 683    
2020-03-19T13:18:12.181-0700 F  -        [initandlisten]     
***aborting after fassert() failure
```

Anyone can help me with this issue?
Best,

Comment: The old version should not matter - as long it is not running!

Answer (score 0):

The error was

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
```

Verify that there is no mongod process already running, remove that file, and then try starting.